# how to remove dot in an url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Certain urls in my site gives 403 - access forbidden error. After doing several hours of research, i found that there is "." (dot) in my url causing the 403 error.  I want to replace all dots to hyphen using .htaccess

for e.g.
i want to change the following url from

http://www.example.com/real-listings/0Bedrooms/commercial-land/TN/For-Sale/SELLING-FIVE-ACRE-LAND./Property.html

TO

http://www.example.com/real-listings/0Bedrooms/commercial-land/TN/For-Sale/SELLING-FIVE-ACRE-LAND/Property.html

Please advise and your help appreciated.

regards,

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to jive with what you want. It simply has the dot removed, it's not being replaced with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules *before* any rules that you may have in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\./([^/]+)(\.html?)$ /$1/$2$3 [L,R=301]
```

Or, if you really wanted to replace that dot with a hyphen:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\./([^/]+)(\.html?)$ /$1-/$2$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry! I'm getting "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @RealestateTamilnadu sorry, typo. Should have been a `,` between `L` and `R` flags, not a `.`