# how to remove dot in an url through htaccess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm getting 403 Access Forbidden error for certain urls.  I found the root cause of the issue. wherever there is a dot(.) in an url, i'm getting the 403 forbidden.

There are thousands of urls have been indexed by google and hence i wanted to resolve via htaccess.

For e.g

I want to remove (dot) for the following url

FROM

```
http://www.example.com/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six./seven/eight.html
```

TO

```
http://www.example.com/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight.html
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove dot in an url using htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862359/how-to-remove-dot-in-an-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

mod rewrite should be able to do that:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?(\.html|php|asp|otherextenstionsdesiredhere$) $1$2$3$4 [NC]
```

Should allow for 1 to 3 periods being removed at a time. If you need more just repeat it a bit more. If it is only 1 period at most, get rid of part of it.
You can test it at http://regexpal.com/ and read more about rewrite at http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php